# selected ID from table 1 to retrieve username from similar id in table 2 vb.net

Tags: vb.net, mysql-workbench

I've have 2 tables. *recipes and foodcategories*

*Recipes table:*

```
ID|     recipe name     |description|FoodCategoryID| 
--+---------------------+-----------+--------------| 
1 | Chicken Soup        | ********* |      3       |
2 | Sunrise Surprise    | ********* |      1       |
3 | Toated Ham & Cheese | ********* |      5       |
```

*Foodcategories table:*

```
FoodCategoryID | FoodCategory |
---------------+--------------|
             1 | Breakfast    |
             2 | Lunch        |
             3 | Dinner       |
             4 | Snack        |
             5 | Brunch       |
```

The recipes table I have displaying on a windows form in datagridview1. Once a user clicks on a row it pops up a new form with several text boxes filled with the data from the row they clicked on. The *textbox* I have a trouble with is the FoodCategory textbox named *CategoryTxTBox*. It displays the FoodCategoryID from the foodcategories table and I need it to display FoodCategory.

The only code I have sofar is:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
    conn.ConnectionString = "Server=; user id=; password=; database=;"
    cmd.Connection = conn
    conn.Open()    
    form2.CatagoryTxtBox.Text = DataGridView1.SelectedCells(5).Value.ToString
end sub
```

But, that only displays the FoodCategoryID.

Please take note that I don't know how to program, I only started yesterday and I'm trying to get it done by myself. unfortunately I can't find any answers regarding this that's why I'm turning to this forum. if anyone has suggestions please.

Comment: show FoodCategory column in datagridview1 at the beginning, then you can view it after directly from the datagridview1

Comment: Yes, if you show the query code that fills the DataGridView it is probably a matter of adding the appropriate JOIN statement to get the FoodCategory description from the second table

Comment: can't i use an if statement? add datagridview2 for foodcategories and if the selected row with the value of FoodCategoryID column = the same FoodCategoryID as the datagridview2 display the FoodCatergory value of datagridview2? not sure what the code will look like though

Answer (score 0):

i solved my question after 100 tries with the following code:

```
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        con.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "Select * from foodcategories where FoodCategoryID = '" & DataGridView1.SelectedCells(5).Value.ToString & "'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, con)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            Dim sname As String
            sname = reader.GetString("FoodCategory")
            RecipeContent.Catagory.Text = sname
        End While
        con.Close()

    Finally
        con.Dispose()
    End Try
```

Please if anyone can tell me if this is the correct way of doing it?